# How to edit output from Ransack's "sort_link" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

As a total noob to Ruby on Rails I have, what I hope, is a fairly simple question.

I'm using the Ransack gem to power my site's search bar and there are a bunch of great methods. One of them is the sort_link method that makes my table of results sortable by clicking on the  element.

The only problem is that when it sorts, it injects `&nbsp;▼` (or `&nbsp;▲`) after the column header name.

All I'm trying to do is edit this output to be `<span>▲</span>` or `<span>▼</span>` instead. After looking everywhere and even asking the question in #rubyonrails IRC I can't seem to find a way customize this output.

As a stop-gap, i've written some javascript to directly manipulate the DOM but it just feels like a dirty approach, especially in a custom site!

Any help here would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here they are in the [Ransack gem source on GitHub](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/constants.rb#L5-L6)

```
# lib/ransack/constants.rb:5-6

module Ransack
  module Constants
    ASC = 'asc'.freeze
    DESC = 'desc'.freeze
    ASC_ARROW = '&#9650;'.freeze   # <- ascending arrow
    DESC_ARROW = '&#9660;'.freeze  # <- descending arrow
# ..snipped..
```

To swap arrow directions, copy the file into your application here: `/lib/ransack/constants.rb` and swap the two HTML entities (or simply swap `ASC_ARROW` and `DESC_ARROW`).

---

**EDIT**

To add a span tag and remove the non-breaking space, we will modify the helper method that handles both.

In [this file](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/dccc871a72da925a8ccf2dd02129fbaa1c30c1f7/lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb#L143-L148) we will take this helper method

```
# lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb:143
def link_name(label_text, dir)
  [ERB::Util.h(label_text), order_indicator_for(dir)]
  .compact
  .join(Ransack::Constants::NON_BREAKING_SPACE)
  .html_safe
end
```

and modify it to:

- Wrap the order indicator arrow in a `span` tag
- Remove `nbsp;`

Copy the [raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/dccc871a72da925a8ccf2dd02129fbaa1c30c1f7/lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb) to your application (to **/lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb**) and change this method to look like:

```
# lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb:143
def link_name(label_text, dir)
  [ERB::Util.h(label_text), content_tag(:span, order_indicator_for(dir))]
  .compact
  .html_safe
end
```

Comment: Nice! So I just replace "ASC_ARROW = '&#9650;'.freeze" with "ASC_ARROW = '<span>&#9650;</span>'.freeze" to get the effect I want?

Comment: Also, I just realized I didnt use code-formatting which may have muddled my question a little. The Sort_Link method injects a nbsp; before the arrow.. Looking at that ransack link, it appears JUST the arrow is defined. Where would the logic to include the nbsp; be?